# Reading multi header excel sheet in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a multi header excel sheet without any index column. When I read the excel in pandas, it treats first column as an index. I want pandas to create an index instead of treating 1st column as an index. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried below code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[1,2], sheetname= "Ratings Inputs", parse_cols ="A:AA", index_col=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my tests, `read_csv` seems broken with a multi_line header: when `index_col` is absent or None, it behaves as is it was 0.

You have 2 possible workarounds here:

1. `reset_index` as suggested by @mounaim:

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[1,2], sheetname= "Ratings Inputs",
                      parse_cols ="A:AA", index_col=None).reset_index()
   ```

   It is almost correct except that the header for first columns are used to name the `MultiIndex` `df.columns` and the first column is named `('index', ''). So you must re-create it:

   ```
   df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(df.columns.names)]
                                      + list(df.columns)[1:])
   ```
2. Read separetely the headers

   ```
   head = pd.read_excel('3x3.xlsx', header=None, sheetname= "Ratings Inputs",
                      parse_cols ="A:AA", skiprows=1, nrows=2)
   df = pd.read_excel(file, header=2, sheetname= "Ratings Inputs",
                      parse_cols ="A:AA", index_col=None).reset_index()
   df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(head.transpose().to_records(index=False)))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :
`your_data_frame.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)`

Comment: When I used "inplace=True", my dataframe returned no values

Comment: check if it has changed by displaying your_data_frame.index , 'inplace'  changes the object inplace and do not return a new one